# Mod_Rewrite existing file check goes pear shaped, or passes wrong querystring

Tags: python, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache, Python (fastcgi), mod_rewrite.

I want

```
http://foo/bar
```

to redirect internally to

```
http://main.py?q=foo/bar
```

Now my .htacess file contains

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
DirectoryIndex main.py

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*) main.py?q=$1
```

Normally works fine. Redirects to main.py with the query-string q=foo/bar
But if I have a script named foo.py it instead directs to foo.py instead of main.py.

I tried removing the RewriteConds and have the RewriteRule alone as a catch-all.

Then it always redirects to main.py ok, but the query-string passed to my script is q=main.py where it should be q=foo/bar

Now there's various kludges I could try involving restructuring my code, file layout etc, but I'd like figure out what's going on before it causes more problems down the track.

So I want to either a) stop it thinking that foo means foo.py or b) make it skip the existing file checks completely and pass on the correct query-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is caused by [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews), which is resolving the non-existent resource `foo/bar` to the existing file `foo.py`, then likely passing it `PATH_INFO` of `/bar`. You can disable it in your `.htaccess` file by modifying your `Options`:

```
Options -MultiViews +ExecCGI
```

Using your original ruleset with `MultiViews` disabled should solve your problem. For the sake of completeness though, the reason why the query string ends up being `q=main.py` is because of the how the request is processed when you remove the rewrite conditions:

- `mod_rewrite` receives the request, and `foo/bar` matches `.*` and is rewritten to `main.py?q=foo/bar`
- `mod_rewrite` performs an internal redirect and assigns itself as the handler
- The redirect is re-processed by `mod_rewrite`, and `main.py` matches `.*` and is rewritten to `main.py?q=main.py`
- `mod_rewrite` performs an internal redirect and assigns itself as the handler
- The redirect is re-processed by `mod_rewrite`, and `main.py` matches `.*` and is rewritten to `main.py?q=main.py`
- `mod_rewrite` realizes that you're going to enter an infinite loop redirecting the same request to itself, and stops the redirection process

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with content negotiation. Try adding...

```
Options -Multiviews
```

...at the top of your .htaccess file.